# Syncing Security Level from Rally to JIRA

Tags: jira, rally, jira-plugin

I'm trying to sync Defects from Rally to Bugs in JIRA (syncing new Bugs from JIRA to Defects in Rally is working fine), but I was getting the following error due to Security Level in JIRA being a required field:

```
[2012-08-16 08:24:52 Z] ERROR : JiraConnection.rescue in attempt_create - Trying to create issue: 'Testing Security Level' resulted in exception SOAP::FaultError
[2012-08-16 08:24:52 Z]  WARN : JiraConnection.initialize - com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: {security=Security Level is required.} : []
```

I created a custom field in Rally with the following properties:

- Name: Security Level
- Display Name: Security Level
- Type: Drop Down List
- Drop Down list Values: None, Reporter and Company, Vendor and Company, Company Only
- Hidden: Unchecked
- Occurrences: 1
- Required: Unchecked

and added the following to my XML configuration:

```
<FieldMapping>
    ...
    <Field><Rally>Security Level</Rally><Other>Security Level</Other></Field>
    ...
</FieldMapping>
<OtherFieldHandlers>
    ...
    <OtherEnumFieldHandler>
        <FieldName>Security Level</FieldName>
        <Mappings>
            <Field><Rally>None</Rally><Other>-1</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Reporter and Company</Rally><Other>10050</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Vendor and Company</Rally><Other>10052</Other></Field>
            <Field><Rally>Company Only</Rally><Other>10031</Other></Field>
        </Mappings>
    </OtherEnumFieldHandler>
    ...
</OtherFieldHandlers>
```

but now it's failing with:

```
[2012-08-16 09:45:32 Z] ERROR : Connector.block in validate - FieldMapping: Rally field "Security Level" not found
[2012-08-16 09:45:32 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.rescue in run_services - Unexpected exception occurred
[2012-08-16 09:45:32 Z] ERROR : ConnectorRunner.exception - Message Invalid Configuration
```

I've tried different combinations of "Security Level", "securityLevel", etc. for the field name in Rally and updated the XML file accordingly when I've tried different combinations, but I always get the same "not found" error.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there a more standard way of mapping Security Level?

Cheers,

Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Rally JIRA Connector cannot sync issues from Rally which require a Security Level in JIRA because the connector only uses the createIssue call and not the createIssueWithSecurityLevel call.

Answer (score 0):

for the field names in Rally, the wsapi strips out spaces and underscores - try just SecurityLevel in the field mapping and in the field handler.
hope that helps

Comment: Hi Dave, using "SecurityLevel" as the fieldname in Rally and in the field mapping and field handler gets me past the 'Rally field "Security Level" not found' error, but no matter what combinations I try I now get "'securityLevelId' failed, invalid JIRA field name". Looking at http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2010/09/issue-via-soap.html you need to use a different method "createIssueWithSecurityLevel" which passes in the ID of the security level as an additional parameter in order to create an issue with a security level in JIRA. Can you create issues with security using the Rally connector?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Looks like you are right in your findings - the connector currently just uses the regular createIssue call.  We can add an item to our backlog to look at supporting the createIssueWithSecurityLevel call.  So far, we had not had any requests about this, but it makes sense.

Comment: Cheers Dave. If it could be added to the backlog that would be great. Thanks, Andrew.